PostgreSQL prepare statement
Note: I do not think this is a PHP question.
PostgreSQL on server #1: PostgreSQL 12.18 (Ubuntu 12.18-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0, 64-bit
Webserver at server #2: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) (with php7_module)
Language at server #2: PHP v7.4
This "raw" SQL does not compute,i.e. it does not replace $1, $2... with parameters supplied:
$query = "SELECT * from $1 WHERE oid = $2";
$param = ['myschema.mytable', 123];
$conn = 'Working Postgres connection.';

Language:
Code:
$queryID = uniqid('pre_', TRUE);
$preparedResource = pg_prepare($conn, $queryID, $query); // <- Returns **FALSE** instead of a resource.
// *Warning: pg_prepare(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1: SELECT * FROM $1 WHERE oid = $2 ^ in ...*
$executedResource = pg_execute($conn, $queryID, $param);
$returnData = pg_fetch_all($executedResource);

Does this function as designed since replaced $1 is not (technically) a parameter or is it a feature?
It works when I substitute text '$1' with first $param item and text '$2' with '$1' i.e. I use "fixed" schema and table refference.

You can't prepare database objects like tables and columns. Only content, because that has a data type like a date or int. What is the real problem? What are you trying to do?

FYI, the duplicate was not "automatically" suggested, your question was closed as duplicate by another user, one with sufficient reputation in [tag:postgresql] to be allowed to singlehandedly close your question.
